# Get text value using Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, dom

I try Simple HTML DOM Parser to get specific text from external website. Here is my code:

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
    $html = file_get_html('http://www.bca.co.id/id/biaya-limit/kurs_counter_bca/kurs_counter_bca_landing.jsp');

foreach ( $html->find('td',13) as $raw) {
    echo $raw->plaintext;
}
```

So far, I get one line result:

```
HKD 1502.30 1470.40
```

HKD is the currency. 1502.30 is the sell rate and 1470.40 is the buy rate.

How to get 1502.30 value only and use it in another PHP files? I want this value can be used to create automatic currency rate conversion. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the `<tr>` block first, loop through the children and retrieve the item you want:

```
foreach ($html->find('tr',5)->children() as $raw) {
    $values[] = $raw->plaintext;   
}
echo $values[1];
```

Output:

```
1502.30
```

Comment: Thank you, it works with Simple HTML DOM Parser. I got a lesson here :)

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use explode? (assuming you always get this like output with spaces)

```
$value = explode(" ",$raw->plaintext);
echo $value[1]; //your desired value
```

Comment: probably work in some case but it doesn't work because I choose wrong tag selector. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The original HTML is this:

```
<tr>
    <td style="text-align:center;">HKD</td>
    <td style="text-align:right;">1502.30</td>
    <td style="text-align:right;">1470.40</td>
    <!-- kolom dua -->
</tr>
```

... so all three values are already separated. You're apparently just not storing them and, instead, simply printing them:

```
foreach ( $html->find('td',13) as $raw) {
    echo $raw->plaintext;
}
```

I've never used that library but it makes more sense to find `<tr>`'s first. Then, there's no problem matching the related values:

```
// Completely untested (I even made up the function names)
foreach ($html->find('tr') as $tr) {
    $cells = $tr->find('td');
    $currency = $cells[0]->getValue();
    $sell = $cells[1]->getValue();
    $buy = $cells[2]->getValue();
}
```

Comment: This explain everything completely. Thank you.